# CSS transform: scale very shaky/choppy/jerky in Safari

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, safari, css-transitions

I'm trying to implement a scroll based shrinking effect on on a div element. As the user scrolls, the div shrinks in height (using `scale`) until it finally disappears. I'm using `React` to render the HTML and `styled-components` for the CSS.

I'm having problems with the performance of this effect, specifically only with Safari, Version 13.1 (15609.1.20.111.8). In Safari, the transition effect is very janky and does not happen smoothly.

Chrome and Firefox work perfectly.

Here is the React component:

```
const MyComponent = React.forwardRef((_, ref) => {
  const [scaleOffset, setScaleOffset] = React.useState(1)

  const onScroll = React.useCallback(debounceWindowEventCallback(() => {
    const paddingOffset = window.scrollY - ref.current.offsetTop
    if (paddingOffset >= 0) setScaleOffset(1 - (paddingOffset / 100))
  }), [ref]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (scaleOffset <= 0) {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', onScroll)
      console.log('Border has been fully shrunk')
    }
  }, [onScroll, scaleOffset])

  React.useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll)
    return () => window.removeEventListener('scroll', onScroll)
  }, [])

  return (
    <RootElement ref={ref}>
      <ShrinkBorderTop scaleOffset={scaleOffset} />
    </RootElement>
  );
});
```

And the relevant styled components are:

```
const ShrinkBorderTop = styled.div`
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  transition: transform .175s ease-out;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  transform: ${({ scaleOffset }) => `scale(1, ${scaleOffset})`};
`
```

What I've tried:

- I initially thought its because my component was rendering too much (every scroll event) so I implemented the `debounceWindowEventCallback` function which uses `window.requestAnimationFrame` to ensure that there's only a single paint per frame. Unfortunately, that didn't help.
- I then tried adding `will-change: transition, transform, height, width;` to `ShrinkBorderTop`, after googling the problem. This also didn't help.
- Then I tried adding `perspective: 1000; backface-visibility: hidden;` to `ShrinkBorderTop`, this also didn't work.

I'm stumped as to what could be causing this problem, in my view its quite a standard animation and I've applied all the performance boosts I'm aware of, in addition to `scale` being hardware accelerated by default, but the problem still persists, only in safari.

What could be causing this?

Comment: Did you tried scale3d ? Or transform with a rotate(0.01deg) => Sometimes it helps ? Or translateZ(0) ?

Comment: Hey @ThéoBenoit thanks heaps for your suggestion! Unfortunately, that didn't help :( I think your logic there is that both `rotate` and `translateZ` are hardware accelerated correct? I believe `scale` should also be hardware accelerated already so maybe that's why it didn't help

Comment: Yeah that was the idea, this things can drive me crazy aha. I have no more idea sadly :/

Comment: Try maybe transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) with the scale. And with all the other techniques maybe, there should be one working